# Python Basemap/Matplotlib Install

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to install the base map for use with matplotlib python v2.7 running on Mac OSX Mavericks. I have all the latest versions of all modules (matplotlib, etc) running using anaconda, but keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simpletest.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
  File "/Users/felishalawrence/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    import _geoslib.so
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/felishalawrence/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_geoslib.so, 2): Library not loaded: libgeos_c.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/felishalawrence/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_geoslib.so
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9/libgeos_c.1.dylib: stat() failed with errno=20
```

Can  someone please give me an idea of what is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: can you put up simple test script to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I entered into anaconda prompt: from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib as mp @kjee

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the following packages with Homebrew:

`brew install numpy`

`brew install proj`

`brew install geos`

`export GEOS_DIR="/usr/local/Cellar/geos/3.10.3/"`